# Why does Torch use so much memory in eval mode?

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to tile up a huge image and feed it into my torch model. My model is on cpu, and the machine has 164 GB RAM.  The thing I want to input is (12000,1,512,512), which is pretty huge, but actually "only" ~13GB if I did my math right.

I try running:

```
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    out = model(in)
```

It fails on memory and claims to be asking for 212+ GB of memory.  Is this just how it is because it wants space for all the intermediate layer outputs, even though no backprop will be happening?

Answer (score -1):

"I tried to compute on a giant input and it gave a memory error" well what did you think was going to happen?

Say your first layer is a convolution that takes the input from (1,512,512) to (64,256,256). That's a 16x increase. To process a 13G input, you would need 208G for the activations of *just the first layer*.

Comment: My 13G input is tiled into 12000 separate small images which are fed as batch.  The intermediate results between layers are still tiny on a per image basis.  It's not like a (1,512,512) thing is 13G.  So my question remains.

Comment: You are feeding 12000 images as a batch. The model is computing on all 12000 items simultaneously. What part of that don't you understand?